# in make all, which target is made up first

Tags: makefile

I have a question about make all command

Example Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: kaldi.done python check_install
```

When I make all,
which of three is done first?

Comment: `make` does not impose an order. The prerequisites will typically be done in the order they are listed if they all need to be made. But if you have a parallel `make` (with the `-j` option) there is no guarantee as to in which order they will finish.

Comment: ... supposing that none of the targets in question is designated as a prerequisite for any of the others.  If build order matters then that's how you should be expressing your constraints.

Comment: Just to note, without parallelism (`-j`) enabled the prerequisites _will_ be built in the order they are listed as prerequisites of the target: this is required by POSIX and all make implementations behave this way.  With `-j` (which is a GNU make-specific, non-POSIX feature so once you use it you're no longer bound by POSIX rules), GNU make will still start the prerequisites in the same order but because the finish time of a prerequisite is non-deterministic you can't know which recipes will run in parallel and which won't.

Comment: In general it's considered poor form to rely on the order that targets appear in the prerequisite list to ensure the order in which recipes are invoked.  If you have a requirement than the recipe for target A must completely run before the recipe for target B is started, then you should make that explicit in your makefile by adding a prerequisite relationiship such as `B: A`